# Share Virtual Box files to Windows Network (

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, ubuntu-10.10

I have a Virtual Box with Ubuntu 10.10 minimal installed. The computers that is running the virtual box is windows 7. How would I be able to access the files in the virtual box from Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install [Guest Additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp11234128) on your Ubuntu, and then use the feature called [Shared Folders](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders).
The name speaks for itself, basically you can link the folder from VirtualBox to the folder on your disk, or even mount it to a separate drive.

How-to's are [here](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/shared-folders-in-virtualbox-on-windows-7/) and [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-access-windows-host-shared-folders-from-ubuntu-guest-in-virtualbox.html).